# .htaccess rewrite with parameters and directory

Tags: php, .htaccess

So i want to rewrite my urls, but I want to know if it is possible to do it, and if it a good idea (you know thinking about what is good practice and what is not).

Let's say I have the following:

[example.com/electronics/tvs/?inches=54&make=sony](http://example.com/electronics/tvs/?inches=54&make=sony)

and I want to rewrite it so tvs is translated to a parameter i.e., category=tvs and also keep the other parameters inches=54&make=sony.

Right now I have the following:

```
RewriteRule ^electronics/([^\/]+)/?(.*) electronics.php?category=$1&$2  [NC,L]
```

But when I try to get the parameters using `$_REQUEST` I am only able to retrive the category parameter.

Comment: Add the `QSA` flag to your flag list `[NC, L, QSA]`. That will append any additional query string parameters. `QSA` = "Query String Append"

Comment: You should have posted as an answer. I worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `QSA` flag to your flag list `[NC, L, QSA]`. That will forward any additional query string parameters on to your script. `QSA` = "Query String Append"

Comment: what about if i want to have options. where it has parameters or just a digit, the option with the digit gets rewritten to have id=89
example.com/electronics/tvs/?inches=54&make=sony
example.com/electronics/tvs/89